# Htaccess Pretty URL prevent access to original directory (duplicate pages)

Tags: .htaccess, duplicates, pretty-urls

**EXPAINATION**

In my htaccess file I have pretty urls set up, such as:

```
RewriteRule ^pricing$ /pages/pricing.php [L]
```

It works as expected, when the user goes to the following url:

```
http://www.example.com/pricing
```

It also works when the user goes to:

```
http://www.example.com/pages/pricing.php
```

**QUESTION**

My question is how can I prevent the user from being able to see the site at:

```
http://www.example.com/pages/pricing.php
```

A 301 redirect only creates a redirect loop.

Any suggestions?